# Send POST to wcf using fiddler cause wcf method empty

Tags: .net, wcf, post

When I send request from html form to this wcf method :

```
public string Save(Stream requestBody)
    {
        var x = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;

        NameValueCollection PostParameters =  
                    HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new 

StreamReader(requestBody).ReadToEnd());
}
```

I get parameters of form body in PostParameters, but Request.QueryString was empty.

But problem is when I use Fiddler and send request - wcf method was fired but method parameter Stream is empty and Request QueryString contains this parameters.

Why sending request from fiddler not put parameters in method parameter?